# error when building with flutter location plugin Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

when I build my android app with [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package I get this error

just adding the package in the pubspec.yaml gives this error even without importing the package in my script

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: C:\Users\Basri\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\Users\Basri\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (124, 1): Class 'FlutterLocationService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: C:\Users\Basri\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (258, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

things I've already tried / project info:

- flutter clean
- flutter upgrade
- gradlew clean
- ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
- gradle version: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

note that when I used the [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin it worked fine, but I need to use the location plugin instead